# MS Access: Use query as control source for textbox

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this query which returns a single value:

```
SELECT Sum(Track.duration) AS [Run time]
FROM Track INNER JOIN ContainsTracks ON Track.trackName = ContainsTracks.tracks
WHERE (((ContainsTracks.albums) Like [Forms]![AlbumDuration Param Query]![Combo1]));
```

I would like this value to appear in a textbox on the same form from which I get the albums value (AlbumDuration Param Query is the name of the form, the query is called AlbumDuration).

I searched this up and found that putting this in the control source of the textbox should work:

```
=DLookUp("Run time","AlbumDuration")
```

But that just displays an error.

**How can I display the contents of my query in a textbox?**

Comment: You can't `Sum` from a `DLOOKUP`. It would be easier to just add this query you have to the form. It will appear as a subform. Then you can simply use the fields as textboxen, like you do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround Run time with square brackets because it contains a space:

```
[Run time]
```